# how to call same module method as instance method and class method in ruby class

Tags: ruby

I want to call the same module method as a class method as well as an instance method in Ruby class. example

```
module Mod1
  def method1
  end
end

class A
end
```

I want to call method1 like
  `A.new.method1` or
  `A.method1`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Karthik mentioned, you can have the class `include` and `extend` the module:

```
module Mod1
  def method1
    'hi'    
  end
end

class A
end

A.include Mod1
A.extend Mod1

A.new.method1 #=> 'hi'
A.method1     #=> 'hi'
```

`A.extend Mod1` is nothing more than

```
A.singleton_class.include Mod1
```

When this is to be done it is not unusual to see the module written as follows.

```
module Mod1
  def method1
    'hi'
  end      
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(self)
  end
end
```

In this case the module need only be `include`d by the class:

```
class A
end

A.include Mod1

A.new.method1 #=> 'hi'
A.method1     #=> 'hi'
```

[Module::included](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-included) is referred to as a *callback* or *hook* method. `A.include Mod1` causes `Mod1::included` to be executed with `klass` equal to `A` and `self` equal to `Mod1`.

As an aside, there are several other callback methods that can be used to good effect. Arguably, the most important are [Module::extended](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-extended), [Module::prepended](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-prepended) and [Class::inherited](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Class.html#method-i-inherited).

Answer (score 1):

I cant imagine this is a good design.. but you can try to both `include` and `extend` the module into the class. `include` adds the methods as instance methods and `e
http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/